# Is there any way to do Partial page refresh on form submit without writing JQuery in Laravel?

Tags: php, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

I know both .NET and PHP and as per my understanding EntityFramework in .NET is same thing as Laravel in PHP.

in .NET we have `@using (Ajax.BeginForm` that renders forms same as `{!! Form::open` in PHP.

`@using (Ajax.BeginForm` does not refresh the whole page on form submit and I don't need to write JQuery to do this. So, basically it acts same as `JQuery.ajax`

**Question:** Is there any way to do Partial page refresh on form submit without writing JQuery in Laravel?

**Bonus Question**
We also have option to pass params like onSuccess, OnComplete, OnBegin and param for passing form css class. Can we do this in Laravel. This is possible in Entity Framework in .NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put: No.

However, you could create your own package that would do this for you.

Create a simple class to open and close your form:

```
namespace Ajaxform;
Class AjaxForm {

    public function begin($action, $method, $options){
        //do other stuff with options, minimal example
        return '<form action="'.$action.'" method="'.$method.'" data-ajax-form/>';
    }
    public function end(){
        return '</form>';
    }
}
```

Then create a Facade accessor:

```
namespace AjaxForm\Facades;
Class AjaxFormFacade extends Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade{
    public static function getFacadeAccessor(){
        return 'ajaxform';
    }
}
```

Then create a service provider that will bind our facade to the application:

```
namespace AjaxForm\Providers;
public function AjaxFormServiceProvider {

    public function bind(){
        $this->publishes([
            __DIR__.'/../assets/' => public_path('vendor/ajaxform')
        ], 'public');
    }

    public function register(){
        $this->app->bind('ajaxform', function(){
            return new AjaxForm;
        }
    }
}
```

Your vendor package would look something like this:

```
MyVendor (replace this with whatever you want)
    - Src
        - AjaxForm
            - assets
                 ajax-form.js
            - Facades
                 AjaxFormFacade.php
            - Providers
                 AjaxFormServiceProvider.php
            AjaxForm.php
```

Your `composer.json` would then look like this inside of  your `AjaxForm` directly (the parent, that comes before the Src directory)

```
{
    "name": "myvendor/ajax-form",
    "version" : "master",
    "description": "An Ajax Form Wrapper.",
    "license" : "MIT",
    "keywords": ["ajaxform"],
    "authors" : [
        {
            "name": "My Name",
            "email": "wheredoigetahold@of.you"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5",
        "illuminate/support": "4.*|5.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Ajaxform\\": "src/AjaxForm/"
        }
    },
  "minimum-stability": "stable"
}
```

Now that you've got your vendor package created, add it to the `config/app.php` file and tell the IOC about our new facade and provider:

Find the `providers` array and add this at the end:

```
MyVendor\AjaxForm\AjaxForm::class
```

Then in the Facades array, add this at the end:

```
'AjaxForm' => 'MyVendor\AjaxForm\AjaxForm::class
```

Now you just need to create the `ajax-form.js` file, which will have our logic for ajaxifying our form.

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('form[data-ajax-form]').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);

        $.ajax({
            method: $this.prop('method'),
            url: $this.prop('action'),
            data: $this.serialize()
        }).done(function(resp){
            //put some logic here
        }).error(function(err){
            //put some logic here
        });
    });
});
```

Now you're ready to call your form:

```
{{AjaxForm::begin(route('path.to.my.endpoint'), 'POST') }}
    //form inputs go in here
{{AjaxForm::end()}}
```